# ajax calendar with dropdownlist issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm using IE6, and I'm trying to work with the ajax calendar extender.  Right beneath it is a dropdownlist.  Most of the answers I found while googling involved setting the z-index.  I added:

 
.ajax__calendar_container { z-index : 9999 ; }
to my css file, and I can see with IE developer toolbar that it's taking the z-index, but it still displays beneath my ddl.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Only resonable way to tackle this is to use IFrame. If possible use many other calendars available in other frameworks (like jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

.ajax__calendar { 
    position: relative; 
    left: 0px !important; 
    top: 0px !important; 
    visibility: visible;  
    display: block;
}

.ajax__calendar iframe
{
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
}

found that adding that in CSS will fix it.